# Why does linkextractor skip link?

Tags: python, web-scraping, hyperlink, scrapy

I am Scraping some pages and am trying to use the LinkExtractor to get the URLs from the response. In general that is going quite ok, but the LinkExtractor is not able to extract the relative link to a pdf file that is found at line 111 of the [html](https://www.limburg.nl/algemeen/zoeken/?mode=zoek&ajax=true&zoeken_sortering=Num&pager_page=4)

I have tried a lot, but haven't been able to figure out how and when the linkextractor drops the relative links, and whether this is how the extractor is supposed to work

```
scrapy shell "https://www.limburg.nl/algemeen/zoeken/?mode=zoek&ajax=true&zoeken_sortering=Num&pager_page=4"
from scrapy.linkextractors import IGNORED_EXTENSIONS
skip_extensions = list(set(IGNORED_EXTENSIONS) - set("pdf")) + ["gz","txt","csv","cls","and","bib","xml","dat","dpr","cfg","bdsproj","dproj","local","tvsconfig","res","dsk"]
extractor = LinkExtractor(deny_extensions=skip_extensions)
extractor.extract_links(response)
```

Comment: `set("pdf")` This is a set of the _individual letters_ `p`, `d`, `f`.  I think you meant `set(["pdf"])` instead.

Comment: @John Gordon Thanks a lot, totally overlooked that. If you post this as an answer, I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`set()` takes a sequence as an argument and makes a set of each item in the sequence.  Strings are sequences of individual characters, so `set("pdf")` makes a set of the characters `p` `d` `f`.

If you want the whole string "pdf" in the set, then you need to enclose it in a list:

```
set(["pdf"])
```

Or it might be simpler to use `{}` notation instead of calling `set()`:

```
{"pdf"}
```